# How can I acess to WhatsApp API with R?

Tags: r, api, whatsapp

I need to download my received WhatsApp messages, including pictures, videos and audio.

I have been trying to download using `{RSelenium}` in [WhatsApp Web](https://web.whatsapp.com/), but this is difficult because the source code only shows what is in the screen.

A few days ago I found the WhatsApp API for Business, but I couldn't find a tutorial teaching how to connect and use it with R.

I have been [trying this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/get-started):

```r
# Initializing API Call
call <- "https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/IDNUMBER"
token <- "AIDHiasudhuiasdhuiasdhasjkdhasuiddghw"

content <- httr::GET(call, httr::add_headers("token-auth" = token))

content

#Response [https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/IDNUMBER]
#  Date: 2022-12-15 19:44
#  Status: 400
#  Content-Type: application/json
#  Size: 151 B

str(httr::content(content))

#$error
#$error$message
#[1] "An access token is required to request this resource."
#
#$error$type
#[1] "OAuthException"
#
#$error$code
#[1] 104
#
#$error$fbtrace_id
#[1] "sdfsdfsdfsdf"
```

Why I have the error `An access token is required to request this resource` ?

How can I check for my received messages?

Comment: This is not a specific programing question and is unlikely to be answered. You're asking for a tutorial, please be more specific.

Comment: You created `content <- httr::GET(..)` then run `httr::content(conteudo)`, is that a typo, or are you looking at a different object? (Or did you really create `conteudo <- httr::GET(..)` and just mis-typed it here in the question?)

Comment: Sorry for my typo. I fixed it.

Comment: [1/2] Trying to "discover" api endpoints and intuit/infer their arguments, functionality, options, etc, is akin to (a) putting together a jigsaw puzzle in the complete absence of light, not knowing its end-shape/size; and (b) doing so with somebody else's puzzle in their own house. There is really no standard to how APIs are structured (names, args, return values). If the provider is interested in you (a non-business (?) non-paying consumer) being able to richly use their API, then they will provide documentation. If they don't, then either they expect you to pay or ... something else.

Comment: [2/2] Having said that, nobody is perfect, perhaps they don't intend for it to be obscure or difficult. Often the best way-forward is to ask them directly. While this is a risk to you since now they know what you're trying to do, but if it's against the user-agreement then you're already on shaky ground. If you're not violating it, then it should be a sure-win.

Comment: @r2evans thanks a lot for your words!